# Counting the number of numbers between each dots in every element of the array in Pandas

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, count

I have column in spreedsheet with IP numbers like;

```
IP
107.57.251.192
219.209.105.108
96.138.34.175
172.135.215.244
89.83.162.207
53.197.57.183
172.53.157.32
```

and I have them inside of an array like

```
array=['107.57.251.192', '219.209.105.108', '96.138.34.175', '172.135.215.244', '89.83.162.207', '53.197.57.183', '172.53.157.32']
```

now I need to create new array, let's call it

```
array2=['3sign.2sign.3sign.3sign', '3sign.3sign.3sign.3sign'...]
```

So I want to count the number of numbers between the dots in every ID number in my array.

I found multiple sources with .count() function but couldn't understand how can I use it in my example with iteration.

```
count1=0
count2=0
count3=0
count4=0

for i in range(len(array)):
    array2[i] = array[i]
    for element in len(array2[i]):
        array2[i] = pd.Series.str.
```

I thought with the above code I will first assign elements to new array, and then for each element with new iteration I will make a function to count 4 counters (because there are 4 sections inside of the IP number between each dot). This is probably bad idea and it's not efficient enough but I start with Python.

Comment: How do you want to store the count? In a dictionary? comma separated list??

Comment: Good question, now I understand it was stupid because the count1, count2... will change for each element of the array. It was only idea how to make objects to assign number of numbers. The result should be like 111.11.1.111 ---.. 3signs.2signs.1sign.3sign. I don't really need to store the count numbers for each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` with `join` as:

```
arr = ['.'.join([str(len(x))+'sign' for x in i.split('.')])  for i in array]

print(arr)
['3sign.2sign.3sign.3sign',
 '3sign.3sign.3sign.3sign',
 '2sign.3sign.2sign.3sign',
 '3sign.3sign.3sign.3sign',
 '2sign.2sign.3sign.3sign',
 '2sign.3sign.2sign.3sign',
 '3sign.2sign.3sign.2sign']
```

Or:

```
arr = ['.'.join(['1'*len(x) for x in i.split('.')])  for i in array]

print(arr)
['111.11.111.111',
 '111.111.111.111',
 '11.111.11.111',
 '111.111.111.111',
 '11.11.111.111',
 '11.111.11.111',
 '111.11.111.11']
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with `re.sub`

```
import re

[
    re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda x: f'{len(x.group(1))}sign', el) for el in array
]
```

```
['3sign.2sign.3sign.3sign',
 '3sign.3sign.3sign.3sign',
 '2sign.3sign.2sign.3sign',
 '3sign.3sign.3sign.3sign',
 '2sign.2sign.3sign.3sign',
 '2sign.3sign.2sign.3sign',
 '3sign.2sign.3sign.2sign']
```